# How to delete a Draft from google play Developer Console?

Tags: android, google-play, publish

I have a test draft on Google Play developer console. It is empty, no apk files on it and no description, I just created it for check something.

Now the draft is here and I can't find a button for delete it.

How can I delete that draft? I can't find any documentation about it.

Thanks.

Comment: Even I faced the same problem, could not figure out a way. Will keep a watch out here if anything of this sort is possible.

Comment: as i know there is no delete button for any apk or content..if there is apk file then you have to unpublished that..this is only way..

Answer (score 4):

As of April 2024, the only way to delete a draft app is to click on the trash icon in your apps list. Also, please keep in mind that the deletion icon will not appear if your app got rejected but still marked as draft.

[image]

Comment: which list view ? how to get there ?

Comment: @Xsmael Select "All Apps" from the left side. You can filter by type (and select "Draft").  There will be a trash icon on each row which is a draft.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i tried but the very app which i wanted to delete didn't have the trash icon, even though it was in draft state, however there were two other apps having the trash icon. I wonder whats wron

Answer (score 4):

1) if you notice this:
[image]

2) go into the release page, then click "discard" as below:
[image]

3) then you remove the "draft"

Answer (score 3):

I searched around and find no way to delete a draft.

However, you can change it's name to your future application (go to Store Listing - Title) and leave your worries behind ^^

Answer (score 3):

Now you have to contact the support to delete an app plus this app needs to be marked as unpublished in `Google Play Console > Version > Configuration > Advanced Settings > Application availability`.

> **Delete an app or game**
>
> You can permanently remove draft apps or games from your Play Console. You can also delete:
>
> - Published apps or games that haven't been installed on any devices
> - Published apps or games that no users are entitled to re-install
>
> In these cases, [contact our support team](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/publishing) to request that your app's or game's data be permanently deleted.

Quoted from https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9023647

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to delete app in the menu available in the right upper corner
[image]

Comment: Upper right corner where? There's nothing in the latest version of the Google Play Console.

Comment: you should have explained which page this is and how to get there, otherwise its completely useless...

Answer (score 1):

On the Apps Listing Page there is a Delete Trash Icon. Click on that and confirm Delete.

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HhYA.png)

Answer (score 1):

Go to All Applications tab, then click the trash button on your app list to delete the draft app.

[image: Go to All Applications tab, then click the trash button on your app list to delete the draft app]

Comment: I see no trash button, they must have removed it

Answer (score 0):

there is a way.

Say you already have a draft and  you want to upload another draft.  Upload the 2nd draft and save it.  It might complain that you cant have two drafts as users can have multiple APKs installed ..fine.

Now archive the original APK (press the archive button).  Now press save.  Now you can use this draft and the other gets archived.

Comment: When I want to archive the only active APK I get the following warning: 

This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):
You must have at least one active APK.

And I cannot press save.. Tried it in the old and new design..

Comment: You cant archive your only active APK, one has to be active, its the rules.  If you dont want the APK active then unpublish the entire app until your ready.  If you had more then one APK active then you could have archived it and chosen another one.